# code works when using window.onload but not document.ready? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

for some reason my document works when I use window.onload = function(){ but not document.ready = function(){

The reason I want to use document ready is that an image i am tweening with tweenmax is not loading as quickly so the animation is off with everything else.

```
    <script> 


    var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
    var topper = document.getElementById("topper");
    var box = document.getElementById("photo");

    window.onload = function() {
        TweenMax.from(box, 4, {height:"200px", width:"200px", top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-100px", ease:Power3.easeIn});
        TweenMax.from(topper, 4, {top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-105px", width:"210px", ease:Power3.easeOut});
        TweenMax.from(footer, 4, {bottom:"50%", left:"50%", marginBottom:"-100px", marginLeft:"-105px", width:"210px", ease:Power3.easeOut});
    };


     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() {});` is a jQuery function, so you would have to add a jQuery reference before you try to run it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 


    var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
    var topper = document.getElementById("topper");
    var box = document.getElementById("photo");

    $(document).ready(function() {
        TweenMax.from(box, 4, {height:"200px", width:"200px", top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-100px", ease:Power3.easeOut}); // <-- edited Power3.easeIn to Power3.easeOut
        TweenMax.from(topper, 4, {top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-105px", width:"210px", ease:Power3.easeOut});
        TweenMax.from(footer, 4, {bottom:"50%", left:"50%", marginBottom:"-100px", marginLeft:"-105px", width:"210px", ease:Power3.easeOut});
    });


</script>
```

EDIT: updated to change

```
TweenMax.from(box, 4, {height:"200px", width:"200px", top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-100px", ease:Power3.easeIn});
```

to

```
TweenMax.from(box, 4, {height:"200px", width:"200px", top:"50%", left:"50%", marginTop:"-100px", marginLeft:"-100px", ease:Power3.easeOut});
```

Comment: hmmm i changed where i was linking my jquery from and it made it work but did not fix my timing problem.... strange. you can see it here after you click "enter"

krismadden.fr

Comment: are you trying to get both the box and the topper/footer to go at the same speed?

Comment: @Kris Looks like it's because the box is easein while the others are easeout. This is causing the box to start slower, while the topper and footer start fast. Then the box ends faster, while the topper and footer end slower. Make all three one or the other and see if they time at the same. Updated answer with change.

Comment: wow. i feel so silly! thank you so much!!! i guess all i needed was an extra pair of eyes!

Comment: @Kris Sometimes that's all it takes, glad I could help! Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload = function(){` is a native javascript function so that is why it is woking while `document.ready` is a jQuery method it needs jQuery to work on. So for this you have to include the jQuery library too.

The doc ready syntax is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning

```
window.onload =function(){
}
```

meant you specified the code that would be executed when the window has loaded.

However, assigning:

```
document.ready=function(){}
```

meant you defined a new function called **ready** for the **document** object, and the function has never been called.Hence, that was the reason why the code wasn't executed.